# Filter relations similar to any? in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Person model which has_many pets. There is a method in Pet model called is_parent?
How do I filter pets of a person based on whether the pets already have child or not?
I want something similar like

```
person = Person.first
person.pets.any? { |pet| pet.is_parent? } # returns true
```

Is there something I can call like person.pets.filter { |pet| pet.is_parent? } and returns all the pets with children?

Thank you

Comment: How's `is_parent?` defined? I ask because if `is_parent?` is an instance method you'll need to traverse all the pets in order to check them, and maybe there's a better way to do that using just SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`select` method from Ruby's Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) module like this

```
person.pets.select { |pet| pet.is_parent? }
```

Which can also be written as

```
person.pets.select(&:is_parent?)
```

---

*That being said, with lots of records it is usually best to do the filtering on the database side.*

Comment: what does it mean filtering on the DB side? how can i do that

Comment: What I mean is that `.select` is done in Ruby code, and will be slower if you have lots of records. If you don't notice any slowless or lag in your app don't worry about it, you can always optimize later.